# Unable to move cursor to next line after reading secret input in shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, shell-script

I am trying to read multiple inputs from user in shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash
read -sp "Enter the secret api key: " var1
read -p "Enter the mount path:" var2
```

If I try to run this, I can not read var2 on separate line.

```
root@ubuntu-test:~/scripts# ./test.sh
Enter the secret api key: Enter the mount path:value2
root@ubuntu-test:~/scripts#
```

I've tried multiple options around read and echo command, but no luck. How do I read var2 on separate line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sole `echo` prints a newline character.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -sp "Enter the secret api key: " var1
echo
read -p "Enter the mount path:" var2
```